# Do we want hats? (2016)

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

The annual winter bash is coming!
This is an event from December 19 to January 8, and users can gain hats for achieving certain goals — similarly to badges.
The hats can be used to to decorate the profile picture, but all hats will be gone for good once the event ends.
It is just some simple holiday fun without greater purpose.

Individual users can opt out from the event if they want.
If we think that hats have no place on this site, we can also opt out as a site.
We need to make the site level decision by Sunday, December 11.

Do we want to take part in the event?

I added some comments below for a simple poll, but answers and other comments are of course welcome.

[See the page of the 2016 Winter Bash here.](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Yes, I want hats! (Poll: upvote this comment if you want hats.)

Comment: No, I don't want hats! (Poll: upvote this comment if you don't want hats.)

Comment: I am indifferent to hats. (Poll: upvote this comment if hats make no difference.)

Comment: **Note:** This question is no longer relevant. If you want to discuss hats, make a new meta question or bring it up in the chat. There will probably be a new hat question for 2017.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The score in the comment poll at the time when decision was due was as follows:

- 7 people want hats.
- 2 people don't want hats.
- 2 people are indifferent to hats.

Given that the event does not require anything from those who want to ignore hats and that any user is free to opt out completely, our site will join the event.

**Note:**
There is a new Winter Bash notification icon next to the familiar message and reputation icons.
You will be notified of your new hats there.
If you want to opt out, click it and choose "I hate hats" in the menu.